# Powershell - including date calulation in export

Tags: powershell, getdate

Team -- trying to expand my powershell script which scans shared drives to include capturing file aging information (see code below).  I tried using the TimeSpan function but it returns blank values.

I tried to simplify the script and use Get-Date -- but it also returns no values while all other data elements do contain information.

I also tried creating a variable $DT = Get-Date and including that ... but it also returns blanks.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
$target_files = Get-ChildItem \\ [source path] \* -recurse -include "*"
$target_files | select-object -Property @{n='Length in MB';e={[math]::Round(($_.Length / 1MB),2)}}, DirectoryName, name, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, New-TimeSpan Get-Date - LastWriteTime |
Export-csv \\ [destination path] \\directoryfiles_Inventory.csv -NoTypeInformation
Import-Csv \\ [destination path] \\directoryfiles_Inventory.csv
```

Comment: You can use a *calculated property* since the parameter expects a property argument. A `[PSCustomobject]` is also an alternative.

Comment: You need to define that last property in a `Hashtable` the same way you are doing for the `Length in MB` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for a Time Difference between `now` and `lastWriteTime` date. If that's the case you can do something like this:

```
$properties = @(
    @{
        Name = 'Length in MB'
        Expression = {[math]::Round(($_.Length / 1MB),2)}
    }
    'DirectoryName'
    'Name'
    'CreationTime'
    'LastWriteTime'
    @{
        Name = 'Time Difference'
        Expression = {
            ([datetime]::Now - $_.LastWriteTime).TotalHours.ToString('#.# Hours')
        }
    }
)

Get-ChildItem . | Select-Object $properties | Export-Csv "C:\destination\path\export.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Each item will look like this:

```
Length in MB    : 0.04
DirectoryName   : C:\Users\example.user
Name            : test.txt
CreationTime    : 4/27/2021 10:12:57 AM
LastWriteTime   : 4/27/2021 10:12:57 AM
Time Difference : 391.8 Hours
```

Comment: Santiago, thank you for your assistance.  I'm seeing the results as I need them in the window however when I add in the export-csv portion of the original code, I get a prompt in the window 
```
cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject:
```

I've foudn some articles explain this problem ... I'm not sure why it would suddenly impact this script

Comment: I eddited the code to show how to export to CSV, you can either save the result in a variable like: `$result = Get-ChildItem . | Select-Object $properties` and then `$result | Export-Csv .....` or you can do like in the code.

Comment: Santiago, many thanks.
Can you recommend any books or youtube videos that would be helpful to a powershell newbie like myself?

Comment: @Matthew I kinda learned by myself, just reading Google. It is a big advantage working on an environment where you can apply the knowledge and practice every day. I did take some courses on PowerShell, I would recommend this course if you're interested in learning the basics: https://www.udemy.com/share/10207MAEMec1tUQnwB/

Comment: Thank you for the suggested course via Udemy -- I'll work it into my training schedule.

So I was able to convert the time difference to 'days' instead of 'hours' ... is it my imagination or is the coversation to 'years' overly complicated.  I was reading through some of hte blog about converting to 'years' and the code seems complicated.  You would think PowerShell would have the coversion built in like hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

Comment: Years would be something like `TotalDays / 365` and you can use `[math]::Round(...)`. It's not hard to do.